# Is it possible to use Tab space to create a horizontal space and then align the texts ? I used \quad and \qquad but it doesn't work

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, itemize, horizontal

```
\begin{itemize}
                \item Structure porteuse (y. c. infrastructure) \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 75 ans
                \item Parapets / bordure de pont \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad   75 ans
                \item Appuis de ponts \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad\quad50 ans
                \item Evacuation des eaux \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \quad50 ans
                \item Etanchéité / revêtement (couche de protection) \qquad \qquad   50 ans
                \item Balllast  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad 35 ans
                \end{itemize}
```

Comment: I would do this using a tabular.  You can put `\textbullet` into the first column.

Comment: Welcome. // Most of the time presenting just 1 line of code is not sufficient. E.g. the preamble holds a lot of relevant information for us. To my observations there will be more answers, when we simply can copy&run your code ... which we can't with a 1-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the `tabto` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\def\t{\tabto{8cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Structure porteuse (y. c. infrastructure) \t 75 ans
    \item Parapets / bordure de pont \t 75 ans
    \item Appuis de ponts \t 50 ans
    \item Evacuation des eaux \t 50 ans
    \item Etanchéité / revêtement (couche de protection) \t 50 ans
    \item Balllast \t 35 ans
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default spacing between two columns is `2\tabcolsep`, but you can replace it by adding `@{\qquad}` (for example) between the columns (`ll`) in the argument list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\textbullet}\hspace{\labelsep}}ll}
  Structure porteuse (y. c. infrastructure) & 75 ans \\
  Parapets / bordure de pont & 75 ans \\
  Appuis de ponts & 50 ans \\
  Evacuation des eaux & 50 ans \\
  Etanchéité / revêtement (couche de protection) & 50 ans \\
  Balllast & 35 ans
\end{tabular}

\begin{itemize}
  \item This is what a normal itemize looks like.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using a makebox:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \makebox[0.5\linewidth]{some text\hfill}see the gap
\item \makebox[0.5\linewidth]{A\hfill}B
\end{itemize}
```